# Is there a way to change/add queue contents dynamically while processing tasks using threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue

I am new to multi-threading but learned this is very useful for my use case. I have an initial queue of tasks to run and the below program approach will help me.

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def do_stuff(q):
  while True:
    print q.get()
    q.task_done()

q = Queue(maxsize=0)
num_threads = 10

for i in range(num_threads):
  worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q,))
  worker.setDaemon(True)
  worker.start()

for x in range(100):
  q.put(x)

q.join()
```

I have researched a lot on if we can change/add the tasks in the queue but haven't got any info. My process initially has some tasks and there are tasks that are to run once these are complete(dependencies-this spans to nearly thousands of tasks). So, I want to keep adding tasks to the queue depending on the success/failure of previous tasks with an upper limit on the number of concurrent threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

With all your comments, it now appears that what you have is 10 independent sets of values creating 10 chains of dependencies:

```
Chain 1: [1, 11, 21, 31, ...]
Chain 2: [2, 12, 22, 32, ...]
...
Chain 10: [10, 20, 30, 40, ...]
```

You can run the first values from each chain as concurrent tasks in a thread pool (i.e. 1, 2, ... 10) and if a task completes successfully, then you can run the next value in the chain, else you are through with that chain since each successive value in a chain is only run on the successful completion of the previous value.

This becomes very simple once you have come up with your method of expressing these chains of dependencies:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def process_x_value(x):
    """
    Process current x value.
    Note that this is invoked by a simple call from run_dependency_chain,
    which is already threaded.
    This function must not be CPU-intensive or else you will not achieve any
    level of concurrency using multithreading.
    """
    import time
    time.sleep(.1) # simulate some I/O
    # return success or failure
    return True # success

def run_dependency_chain(x):
    """
    Process value x, if sucessful process next x value that was dependent
    on successful completion.
    Repeat until there is no next x value (end of dependency chain).
    """
    while True:
        result = process_x_value(x)
        if not result: # failure
            return
        results[x] = True # just store successful results
        x = next_x.get(x)
        if x is None:
            return


# we will be running 10 concurrent dependency chains:
# if task 1 completes successfully, next task to run is 11
# if task 2 completes successfully, next task to run is 12
# ...
# if task 10 completes successfully, next task to run is 20
"""
Thus the successor task can be computed by adding 10 to the current task,
but we will assume in general a more complicated relationship is possible. So we will
use a quasi-linked list of dependencies implemented using a dictionary, next_x,
where next_x[x] gives the successor x to be run on successful completion
of task x.
"""
# at most 2000 successful tasks:
next_x = {x: x + 10 for x in range(1, 1991)}

# to hold results, if you are interested:
results = {}
pool = Pool(10)
pool.map(run_dependency_chain, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
print(len(results)) # number of succesful results
```

Prints:

```
2000
```

If `process_x_value` is sufficiently I/O bound, multithreading should reduce your running time by a factor of almost 10.

Comment: Sorry for tagging multiprocessing - I tagged it because I wanted to explore if there's an easier way to do this in multiprocessing. My function doesn't do anything cpu intensive but triggers a subprocess and waits for its return value - so multithreading does the job. Depending on the return value, I add the next tasks to the queue. In your answer, does tuple (10,0,20,90,15) indicate the task numbers that are successful? Can you elaborate on where we are adding tasks into queue even when the threads are running.

Comment: I updated the answer with a small discussion. But it is no substitute for reading the docs.

Comment: I understood that. Is there a way to add to the existing and same queue(like adding another task to it when a thread sends task_done status?)

Comment: I don't fully understand you last comment. I thought my code demonstrates how to submit a task with `apply_async` and wait for a result by calling `get` on the `AsyncResult` instance returned by `apply_async`. That is your "task_done" status. You can then submit more tasks based on the result. `apply_async` also supports specifying a callback function that receives the result (return value) as soon as the processing is complete.

Comment: 1) yes, I got that. What we have in the code is we create a queue, submit it and wait for their return code. My function remains the same for all tasks and the number of tasks is huge(2000+). In this case, creating 10 tasks for each queue and calling queue(s) one after the other is not possible. Instead what I wish to do is, create a queue(Let's call it queue1) with 10 tasks, submit it.

Comment: 2)  Right at the time when one of these 10 tasks is complete, add 11th task to queue1 since one thread is free now and so on for all tasks. I hope this makes sense. This 11th task, for example, cannot be added initially since it only runs when the return code of the earlier task is successful.

Comment: You have 2000 tasks. You submit the first 10. Great. but let's say the first one completes unsuccessfully? What do you plan on doing with the other 1990 tasks? So when you say, "This 11th task, for example, cannot be added initially since it only runs when the return code of the earlier task is successful", you are not specifying *fully* what happens when it completes but the return code is unsuccessful.

Comment: I have a table that marks the dependencies to run one after the other. An entry for task 11 will be available in the table with dependency on task 1. Likewise there will be another task 12 which is dependent on task 2 and so on. So if a task(task1) completes with rc as unsuccessful, my function that adds tasks to queue will not add task11 to queue, it waits for next successful complete of task. If task2 is complete successfully - it adds task 12 to the queue. It just ignores the next dependency tasks by not adding them(similar to job scheduling one after the other with dependencies).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232750/discussion-between-batman-and-booboo).